# ToUpper() is changing sometimes the character (µ -> M)

Tags: c#, .net, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net micro (µ) greek letter uppercase issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616984/net-micro-greek-letter-uppercase-issue)

I have a function that is converting all string to uppercase. I'm just using `string.ToUpper()` method.

Well it's working. But for some characters ToUpper() is doing weird stuff. Like for `µ`, a `µ.ToUpper()` is an `M`. Why? How can I avoid this? Just UpperCase chars if there is an upper case character :)?

Comment: `µ` is the Greek letter Mu.

Capital is M :)

Comment: Have you checked the current culture?

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx to understand CultureInfo

Comment: @E.T. oh! Good to know. So actually this is not a C#/.NET issue, it's more an issue with my greek skills :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`String.ToUpperInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx).

In this method, the invariant culture is used.

This method is exactly the same as calling `myString.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: +1. I've stolen your `ToUpperInvariant`

Comment: Well, it won't make my day, buy anyway - cheers)

Answer (score 5):

Specify culture or use **[InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)** when doing string transformations. For example:

```
"µ".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
"µ".ToUpperInvariant()
```

returns `µ`

Answer (score 0):

It's most probabbly *culture related issue*, use a [String.ToUpper Method (CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), where you can specify *Invariant* culture.